# Script adding too many users. How can I limit additions?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I have a script with 2 Foreach loops. The first works with no issues, but when I add the second it adds every user value in the column to each Team. I can't see where/why its going wrong and I'm hoping someone can point it out to me.

```
#Read team users from CSV file
$teams = import-csv "File_Path"
#Iterate team user details one by one
Foreach($team in $teams)
{
$DisplayName = $teams.'TeamDesc'
$Description = $teams.'Code'
$Visibility = $teams.'Visibility'
$Owner = $teams.’UserPrincipleName’


$group = New-Team -DisplayName $team.TeamDesc -Owner $team.UserPrincipleName -Description $team.Code -Visibility $team.Visibility

Foreach($team in $teams)
{
$Group = (Get-Team -DisplayName $team.'TeamDesc').GroupId
$User = $teams.'DepartmentChair'

Add-TeamUser -GroupId $group.GroupId -User $team.'DepartmentChair' -Role ‘Owner’ 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not understanding why you're doing the exact same loop, twice, one inside the other, but that's likely your problem. If I summarise your code, with some indenting, it looks like the following:

```
Foreach($team in $teams)
{
   ...
   Foreach($team in $teams)
   {
   }
}
```

Perhaps you meant to have the second 'for' loop *outside* (i.e. *after*) the first one. Alternatively, perhaps you meant to loop through something else in the 2nd loop, like a list of users.